# using jQuery to get attribute value for all links on a page

Tags: jquery

All my links on HTML page are the following format with different class names.

```
<a class="Button" href="https://xyz.cdf/abc" onclick="ABC_A('xpid',':xyz:cdf',this.href);  return false;">Button Click</a>
```

All my "onclick" value starts with ABC_A. I am trying to capture the value of "onclick" with the following but it returns empty "".

```
jQuery( "a[onclick^='ABC_A']" ).val();
```

Is there a way I can avoid using individual class name as it's different from link to link? or i am going about the completely wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val` is for `input` and other form fields. You want `.attr('onclick')`. That will only get the first element's value, but you need to use `.each`.